# Copying from file: read psql message on windows with UTF8

Tags: windows, postgresql, import, console, psql

I'm trying to import csv file to postgres with COPY command.
As I've received well known 'ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9f in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"' I changed my client_encoding to utf8.
Now I'm getting completely unreadable message
ÐŸÐžÐœÐ˜Ð›ÐšÐ:  Ð²Ñ–Ð´Ð½Ð¾ÑˆÐµÐ½Ð½Ñ "mytab" Ð½Ðµ Ñ–ÑÐ½ÑƒÑ”

I tried to change console codepage by chcp 65001 but with no luck.
Can anybody help me with that extraordinary rare and complex task - to import csv to database?

Comment: Then please give us the everyday and simple information what the encoding of your CSV file is and what database encoding you are using in PostgreSQL. Also, tell us what client encoding your PostgreSQL client is using.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:

I would suggest, that **problem** is due to UA or RU **localization of installed DB**.

Switching DB lang should help (at least hepled me):

```
SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

Please try on your PC and let me know if that helps.

---

**My investigation**:

In the powerShell I all the time getting an error but with:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9f in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

When I swith encoding to UTF-8 with comand:

```
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

I'm starting to get the same **not readable symbols**, but if I going to pgAdmin4 and run the same command it gives me well explained error in UA lang:

```
ERROR: ПОМИЛКА:  insert або update в таблиці "exam_results" порушує обмеження зовнішнього ключа "exam_results_subject_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Ключ (subject_id)=(0) не присутній в таблиці "subjects".
CONTEXT:  SQL-оператор "insert into exam_results (student_id, subject_id, mark) 
        values ((random()*100000)::int,
                (random()*1000)::int,
                (random()*5)::int)"
Функція PL/pgSQL inline_code_block рядок 4 в SQL-оператор
```